# How to obtain a list of columns returned by a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In SQL Server, how can I query the system tables to return all the column names of a stored procedure? For a view, I know I can use `sp_columns` or `sys.columns`. But when I use those against my stored procedure, it returned 0 rows.

I have tried the following:

```
EXEC sp_columns MyStoredProc;
```

and:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('MyStoredProc');
```

Both returned nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: as far as i know sproc is the programming side of SQL where not necessarily will return a value... unlike a function or tbv

Comment: I guess I would have to ask why you need the column list. A stored procedure isn't like a table. Many (most?) don't even have an output, let alone a static one, so it's probably impossible to get at what you want programmatically. On the other hand, if you just need to document your output, you could do an ad hoc run where you drop your results into a table, profile that table for your documentation, then drop it.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu  thanks for explanation

Comment: @EricBrandt thanks for explanation

Answer (score 8):

If you are asking for SQL 2012 or later, you can use

```
exec sp_describe_first_result_set N'your-stored-procedure-name'
```

Note: This will return the **first result set** returned by your stored procedure.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I am on SQL Server 2016, so this worked out for me

Comment: this will not work if you have temporary tables in your stored procedure